# SQL multi-part identifier can't be bound in SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, syntax-error, case

Is it possible to add a case using a column from other tables than first in the from section?

I can't use anything like **C**.code or **Y**.anything in the SELECT part:

```
SELECT 
    fromTableA, fromTableA, fromTableA,  
    CASE   
        WHEN fromTableA = anyValue THEN 'is_ok'  
        WHEN B.fromTableB = anyValue THEN 'couldnt.be.bound'
        WHEN   fromTableB = anyValue THEN 'invalid.column.name'
    END AS X  
FROM
    (SELECT fromTableA,
     SUM(fromTableA),
     CASE WHEN A.fromTableA = 'anything' THEN 'still ok'
          WHEN C.fromTableC = 'allowed' THEN 'no problem'
     FROM tableA A
     JOIN tableB B ON A.id = B.id  
     JOIN tableC C ON C.id = B.id
     Having SUM(fromTableA) > 0
     ) AS Y
```

Edit: What I need is to use columns from table B or C in the outer Select ( I just can't remove the inner select because i would lost cases and aggregation operations there are in the inner select).

Comment: Why the sub-query?    Without it, you can reference the table aliases.

Comment: Are you saying that the `from` clause cannot be altered in any way and _must_ be a subquery? It isn't clear why changing the `from` clause would change the number of rows, e.g. adding `C.ShoeSize as SomethingIReallyNeedFromTheTableDesignatedByTheTableAliasC` to the select list in the subquery wouldn't add three more rows to the result set. Can you add subqueries to the outer `select` statement's select list?

Answer (score 2):

The following should be all you need, a derived table here doesn't accomplish anything.

```
select A.Cols...,  
case 
  when A.col1 = anyValue then 'is_ok'  
  when B.Col1 = anyValue then 'couldnt.be.bound'
  when B.Col2 = anyValue then 'invalid.column.name'
end as X  
from tableA A
join tableB B on A.id = B.id  
join tableC C on C.id = B.id;
```